# getting the country name from Coordinates (used CLLocationManager)

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the country name/ code from the coordinates that I get using CLLocationManager but I can t find a suitable function for that :

I found that there is something called MKReverseGeocoder and found several tutorials on it , but when I write that in my code it gives me a warning saying that it was deprecated .

what is the alternative , is there any tutorial for that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MKReverseGeocoder` is deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use the `CLGeocoder` class instead.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder

Comment: Note that CLGeocoder is not available on OS X as of 10.10 and MKReverseGeocoder is not deprecated.